# How to load Bitmap Images into Picasso imageloder

Tags: android, picasso

When i load bitmap it shows cannot resolve load(android.Graphic.Bitmap), is there any alternative to show bitmaps in imageview.

```
    Picasso.with(mContext.getApplicationContext())
            .load(model.getBitmap()) // return Bitmap object
            .resize(100, 100)
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.mAlbumImage);
```

Comment: Picasso is good no problem till now. Try with updated Picasso lib

Comment: If you already have a bitmap then you can show using `imageView.setImageBitmap(yourbitmap);`

Answer (score 0):

Picasso image loader is good but there are also many image loader which are better than picasso like.

[Universal ImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

[Facebook fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco)